# SQL MERGE syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

Is there not a cleaner way to write this query?

```
MERGE INTO TARGET_TABLE AS t
USING SOURCE_TABLE AS s
    ON t.LOCAL_ID = s.LOCAL_ID
WHEN MATCHED
    AND (
        t.[col1] <> s.[col1]
        OR t.[col2] <> s.[col2]
        OR t.[col5] <> s.[col5]
        OR t.[col6] <> s.[col6]
        OR t.[col8] <> s.[col8]
        OR t.[col13] <> s.[col13]
        OR t.[col15] <> s.[col15]
        )
    THEN
        UPDATE
        SET [col1] = s.[col1]
            ,[col2] = s.[col2]
            ,[col5] = s.[col5]
            ,[col6] = s.[col6]
            ,[col8] = s.[col8]
            ,[col13] = s.[col13]
            ,[col15] = s.[col15]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN
        INSERT (
            [LOCAL_ID]
            ,[col1]
            ,[col2]
            ,[col5]
            ,[col6]
            ,[col8]
            ,[col13]
            ,[col15]
            )
        VALUES (
            ,s.[LOCAL_ID]
            ,[col1]
            ,[col2]
            ,[col5]
            ,[col6]
            ,[col8]
            ,[col13]
            ,[col15]
            )
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
    THEN
        DELETE
OUTPUT GetDate()
    ,s.LOCAL_ID
    ,$ACTION
    ,deleted.[col1] col1
    ,deleted.[col2] col2
    ,deleted.[col5] col5
    ,deleted.[col6] col6
    ,deleted.[col8] col8
    ,deleted.[col13] col13
    ,deleted.[col15] col15
    ,inserted.[col1] NEW_col1
    ,inserted.[col2] NEW_col2
    ,inserted.[col5] NEW_col5
    ,inserted.[col6] NEW_col6
    ,inserted.[col8] NEW_col8
    ,inserted.[col13] NEW_col13
    ,inserted.[col15] NEW_col15
INTO [AUDIT];
```

the columns are a subset of both tables, so I don't think the wildcard will help me much.

Both tables are identical in field names however. `AUDIT` can contain `deleted.*` and `inserted.*` inside of specifically picking columns

Comment: I don't understand what's not "clean" about it.  It clearly specifies the source, target and that you want to insert/update/delete according to a set of rules.  Looks clean to me.  If you don't like the `MERGE` statement, you could always use separate Insert, Update and Delete statements, wrapped in `If Exists` and `If Not Exists` logic like the olden days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as good as it gets. You could use dynamic SQL, of course.